# Cannot load such file -- ffi_c error in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, rubymine

I tried to run a simple script as follows to learn automation using watir-webdriver and Ruby. But I am getting no such class error -ffi_c.

```
class TestWatir
  require 'watir-webdriver'
  require 'cucumber'
  browser = Watir :: Browser.new :firefox
  browser.goto 'http://www.google.com'
end
```

I've added Cucumber and Watir-webdriver gems and also checked there is ffi dependency in the external library.

Comment: What does your `Gemfile` look like? Did everything install successfully with `bundle install`?

Comment: line 4 should be `browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox` (no spaces around `::`).

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65000467/12544391, e.g. adding `gem "ffi"` to `Gemfile` fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem and resolved it by:

```
del Gemfile.lock
bundle clean --force
gem install bundler -v 1.12.1
gem install ffi -v 1.9.10 --platform=ruby
bundle install
```

It seams that some versions of ffi era labeled with the incorrect platform or something like that, that's bringing some problems on windows.

Hope it helps!